# On a dual head system, how can I force the placement of a window to a certain desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, xrandr, unity

The relevant output of my xrandr configuration:

```
xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2304 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)      

VGA1 connected 1280x1024+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Just as an examle; let's say I would launch gvim from the commandline, how could I force the application window to be displayed on output `VGA1`?

As a desktop environment I am using **Unity** with **compiz** enabled. 
Maybe there's a way to do this within compiz if I can't do it straight from the cli (which I would prefer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the position and size of the Gvim window through the [`-geometry` command line option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#-geometry). This is common to a lot of X11 applications. The syntax of the [geometry specification](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/X.7.html#sect6) is `${width}x${height}+${x}+${y}`, and you can omit the size or position if you want to only set one.

```
gvim -geometry +1024+0
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. 
I should have made it clearer in my question. Using `gvim` as an application was just an example. 
The solution should be agnostic to a certain applications implementation of its window placements. 
E.g. when using `feh` to display an image, your approach would not work. Also feh just being an application chosen for the sake of example

Comment: @elementz A lot of X applications support `-geometry`. With feh, you need to pass `--geometry`. You need application support or window manager support, you can't do this fully reliably from a third-party tool (the best you could do from a third-party tool is detect new windows and reposition them after the fact).

Comment: Just checked, the `--geometry` switch is actually available in feh, but it does not allow to control the placement of a fullscreen window when using `-F`. 
Either way, an application agnostic approach would be what I am looking for.